# Lighttpd Rewrite Rule (match not having a period)

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I am trying to figure out a `rewrite` rule for `lighttpd` that will behave in the following way:

If the uri *(the part after the protocol and domain)* does **not** contain a `period` execute the rule.

Examples:

```
uri = "/people/add"
Should run the rule.

uri = "/js/main.js"
Should NOT run the rule.

uri = "/people.php"
Should NOT run the rule.
```

Here is what I have so far, but it does not behave as expected, it always runs the rule:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(my\.domain\.com)$" {
    url.rewrite-once = (
            "^/(.*)$" => "index.php/$1"
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the following for your regex?  I'm not familiar with the syntax lighthttpd supports, but if it supports character classes, below should do what you are asking.

```
 "^/([^.]+)$"
```